# In-memory database, for integration tests, loses all data after calling RestTemplate method

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa, testing

I am trying to write some tests for REST api but my in-memory database seems to drop all its data after I call any endpoint using `RestTemplate`. Before sending any requests data is in the database but when `@RestController` is called then data is lost.

**Test file:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class EventServiceTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int randomServerPort;

    //@Autowired stuff

    @Test
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:beforeEventTest.sql")
    public void createTest() {
        String createUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/api/event";
        EventComponents eventComponents = eventUtils.getEventComponents();
        EventDto eventDto = new EventDto(
                "testEvent",
                eventComponents.getAddressDto(),
                eventComponents.getCategoryDto(),
                eventComponents.getSubcategoryDto(),
                eventComponents.getPerformerDtos(),
                new Date(),
                new Date()
        );
        RestTemplate createTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // at this point there are some records in database
        cityDao.findAll().forEach(e-> System.out.println(e.getName()+" TEST")); // data is printed so it is saved in db
        CreateEventResponse response = createTemplate.postForObject(createUrl, eventDto, CreateEventResponse.class);
        //assertions
    }
}
```

**Rest controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EventController {
    private EventProcess eventProcess;

    @Autowired
    private CityDao cityDao; //for checking if data is in database

    public EventController(EventProcess eventProcess) {
        this.eventProcess = eventProcess;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CreateEventResponse create(@RequestBody EventDto eventDto) {
        //at this point there is nothing in db, but there should be some saved records
        // because earlier in test there were persisted records
        cityDao.findAll().forEach(e-> System.out.println(e.getName()+" CONTROLLER")); //nothing is printed
        return this.eventProcess.create(eventDto);
    }
}
```

*EDIT: Changed from programmaticaly preparing db to using .sql script*

I am really confused by this because at first I wrote really terrible piece of code to prepare my test data but it passed all assertions. Now there is .sql file for preparing db for tests but it stopped working because as I said earlier, data seems to get deleted when calling `restTemplate.postForObject()`.

**Test file before refactoring (passes)**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class EventServiceTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int randomServerPort;

    private static final ArrayList<PerformerDto> performerDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<CategoryDto> categoryDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<SubcategoryDto> subcategoryDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<CityDto> cityDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<CountryDto> countryDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<LocationCategoryDto> locationCategoryDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<LocationDto> locationDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<AddressDto> addressDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    //@Autowired stuff

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepareData() {
        performerDtos.add(new PerformerDto("a"));
        performerDtos.add(new PerformerDto("ab"));
        performerDtos.add(new PerformerDto("abc"));
        performerDtos.add(new PerformerDto("abcd"));
        performerDtos.add(new PerformerDto("abcde"));

        categoryDtos.add(new CategoryDto("Music"));
        categoryDtos.add(new CategoryDto("Sport"));

        subcategoryDtos.add(new SubcategoryDto("Concert"));
        subcategoryDtos.add(new SubcategoryDto("Festival"));
        subcategoryDtos.add(new SubcategoryDto("Football"));
        subcategoryDtos.add(new SubcategoryDto("Basketball"));

        cityDtos.add(new CityDto("Warsaw"));
        cityDtos.add(new CityDto("Wroclaw"));

        countryDtos.add(new CountryDto("Poland"));
        countryDtos.add(new CountryDto("Russia"));

        locationCategoryDtos.add(new LocationCategoryDto(LocationType.INDOOR));
        locationCategoryDtos.add(new LocationCategoryDto(LocationType.OUTDOOR));

        locationDtos.add(new LocationDto(locationCategoryDtos.get(0), countryDtos.get(0), cityDtos.get(0)));
        locationDtos.add(new LocationDto(locationCategoryDtos.get(1), countryDtos.get(0), cityDtos.get(1)));

        addressDtos.add(new AddressDto("Test street 32A", "12", locationDtos.get(0)));
        addressDtos.add(new AddressDto("Klonowa 50", null, locationDtos.get(1)));
    }

    @Before
    @Transactional
    public void ensureData() {
        ensurePerformers();
        ensureCategories();
        ensureSubcategories();
        ensureAddress();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensurePerformers() {
        performerDtos.forEach(performerDto -> {
            if (performerDao.findByName(performerDto.getName()) == null)
                performerDao.save(new Performer(performerDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureCategories() {
        categoryDtos.forEach(categoryDto -> {
            if (categoryDao.findByName(categoryDto.getName()) == null)
                categoryDao.save(new Category(categoryDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureSubcategories() {
        subcategoryDtos.forEach(subcategoryDto -> {
            if (subcategoryDao.findByName(subcategoryDto.getName()) == null)
                subcategoryDao.save(new Subcategory(subcategoryDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureCities() {
        cityDtos.forEach(cityDto -> {
            if (cityDao.findByName(cityDto.getName()) == null)
                cityDao.save(new City(cityDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureCountries() {
        countryDtos.forEach(countryDto -> {
            if (countryDao.findByName(countryDto.getName()) == null)
                countryDao.save(new Country(countryDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureLocationCategory() {
        locationCategoryDtos.forEach(locationCategoryDto -> {
            if (locationCategoryDao.findByLocationType(locationCategoryDto.getLocationType()) == null)
                locationCategoryDao.save(new LocationCategory(locationCategoryDto));
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureLocation() {
        ensureLocationCategory();
        ensureCities();
        ensureCountries();
        locationDtos.forEach(locationDto -> {
            if (locationDao.find(locationDto) == null)
                locationDao.save(locationDto);
        });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void ensureAddress() {
        ensureLocation();
        addressDtos.forEach(addressDto -> {
            if (addressDao.find(addressDto) == null)
                addressDao.save(addressDto);
        });
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createTest() {
        String createUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/api/event";
        AddressDto addressDto = addressDtos.get(0);
        CategoryDto categoryDto = categoryDtos.get(0);
        SubcategoryDto subcategoryDto = subcategoryDtos.get(0);
        ArrayList<PerformerDto> performerDtos = new ArrayList<>(EventServiceTests.performerDtos.subList(0, 3));
        EventDto eventDto = new EventDto("testEvent", addressDto, categoryDto, subcategoryDto, performerDtos, new Date(), new Date());
        RestTemplate createTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        CreateEventResponse response = createTemplate.postForObject(createUrl, eventDto, CreateEventResponse.class);
        //assertions
    }
}
```

**Sql script:**

```
DELETE FROM address;
DELETE FROM location;
DELETE FROM city;
DELETE FROM country;
DELETE FROM performer;
DELETE FROM category;
DELETE FROM subcategory;
DELETE FROM location_category;

INSERT INTO city VALUES (1,null,null,'London');
INSERT INTO country VALUES (1,null,null,'England');
INSERT INTO performer VALUES (1, null,null,'a');
INSERT INTO performer VALUES (2, null,null,'b');
INSERT INTO performer VALUES (3, null,null,'c');
INSERT INTO performer VALUES (4, null,null,'d');
INSERT INTO category VALUES (1, null,null,'Music');
INSERT INTO subcategory VALUES(1,null,null,'Concert');
INSERT INTO location_category VALUES(1,null,null,'INDOOR');
INSERT INTO location values (1,null,null,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO address values (1,null,null,15,'test 12A',1);
```

Comment: The problem is thus most probably in eventUtils

Comment: @JBNizet I will put eventUtils in the post in a minute but I don't know why it might be the issue, because its job is to ensure that required data is saved in database before execution of "createTest()" and  it looks like it does the job. The problem is that this data is later lost

Comment: Well, given that the data can't be found in the database, my guess is that it doesn't do the job.

Comment: But there are records in db when I run the test, problem is that I don't know why these records are lost as soon as I get to the controller.

Comment: Now I am using `@Sql` to setup my test data but I still have the same problem - data at some point gets deleted